# Pasting images into Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, image, copy-paste

I am looking for a way to enable my users to paste images into my Silverlight component (into a TextBox, I guess, or is there any better control for doing this?).

From what I read on the internet, for security reasons, there is no clipboard access from code, except by using a JavaScript function that works only with IE.

But what if the user invokes the browser command (Ctrl-V or menu) to paste the data?
I can see it works with text, so I am wondering if I can do the same for pictures.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to get access to images from a user's compter is via a [OpenFileDialog](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2008/10/25/cool-silverlight-trick-5.aspx). Copy/paste isn't going to work.

Comment: Just what I feared. Thanks for confirming.